Do I need a node.js server for Laravel Reverb?
Hello I've got a question, beacause I still don't understand that topic well and I'm beginner in that, I want to build web application where will be included realtime chat.For websockets I want to use Laravel Reverb. If I'll want host that app somwhere on web-hosting, will be node.js server needed for that(for using websockets) ? I mean, if webhosting, where I will host web app, must have support for node.js server?

No, you don't need any support for Node.js to run the Laravel Reverb package since this package is built entirely on PHP and Laravel components.
Of course, you can still build a chat application where your WebSocket server is written in Node.js, but in the case of Laravel Reverb, you don't need Node.js at all for the realtime part.

No, you don't
As laravel reverb is first party application which can be run through artisan command with debug flag
Debug to view logs & staus while development
php artisan reverb:start --debug 

In production - Linux Ubuntu
Supervisor can be used to execute this reverb application without causing any system blocks.
Check this reference for supervisor
How to use supervisor to process jobs in Laravel?
Supervisor Laravel Reverb Conf

Install & Add new supervisor configuration


sudo apt-get install supervisor
nano /etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-reverb.conf


laravel-reverb.conf add this command in file



Reread & Start laravel reverb

Do not use numprocs>1 it shouldbe 1 otherwise reverb will throw port already in used error and your laravel.log will become too heavy

sudo supervisorctl reread 

sudo supervisorctl update  

sudo supervisorctl start laravel-reverb:*


